# One application two webview but only one localStorage

Tags: html, webview, local-storage

I have an app,in my app there are two webviews,I marked webview_One and webview_Two.

```
webview_One access "http://localhost:12345:/a/index.html"
webview_Two access "http://localhost:12345:/b/index.html"
```

in a/index.html and b/index.html I used localStorage to operate one variable both are localStorage.test
but, when I changed localStorage.test in a/index.html,in b/index.html I got the value which was changed in a/index.html

Why each webview can't store the localStorage?

I want to know how can I let each webview store each webview itselfe localStorage value?

Answer (score 0):

The WebKit only uses one database for local storage - look at documentation for WebSettings

sessionStorage on the other hand will probably do what you want, but you will lose the data whn you navigate away from the page

Comment: Why can't you use session storage? Have you enabled it for the web view ?